# What can I say about the form of an invariant function?

Tags: functions, symmetry, invariance

I have a general scalar function which has the properties:
\begin{align}
f(s\,a,b,c)&=s\,f(a,b,c)\\
f(s\,a,s\,b,s\,c)&=f(a,b,c)
\end{align}

where $s$ can be any real number, so the invariance is continous. How far can I restrict the function $f$ now?
My approach is: $f$ is linear in $a$ and can be decomposed by a function $g$ that transforms as:
\begin{align}
f(a,b,c)&=a\cdot g(b,c)\\
g(s\,b,s \,c)&=\frac{1}{s} g(b,c)
\end{align}

Can I further restrict $g$ from that tranformation law?

Especially can I assume any analytical form for $g$? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

$g(b,c)$ will be a constant times $b^pc^q$, where $p+q=-1$

**Note** as mentioned in the comment, $g(b,c)=h(\frac bc)b^pc^q$. The function $h$ depends only on the ratio of the $b$ and $c$ numbers.

Comment: Are you sure that this is true?
Take the function $g(b,c)=\frac{b^2}{(b^2+c^2)^{3/2}}$. This transforms to $1/s$ if p and q $\rightarrow$s*q. But I cant find a $p$ such that the equality holds for all b and c.

Comment: You are right. The "constant" that I've mentioned is a number that does not depend on the magnitude of $b$ or $c$ directly, but it's a function of the ratio of the two.

Comment: okay. I try to understand this thank you. Can you give me a hint what brings you to this conclusion?

Comment: Write $b=r\cos\theta$ and $c=r\sin\theta$. Since you multiply with $s$, if you expand $g$ in powers of $b$ and $c$, you have all terms with $p+q=-1$. So one more correction to make: $$g(b,c)=\sum_{p\in \mathbb R}h_p\left(\frac bc\right)b^pc^{-1-p}$$

Comment: I do not understand this notation of the sum running over all p in Reals. What do you mean by that? also is $h_p$ a function or a constant now?

Comment: If you use polar notation, $h_p$ is a function of $\theta$. The sum over reals means that any for any $p$ you have that $(sb)^p(sc)^{-1-p}=\frac 1s b^pc^{-1-p}$. What it means that I can write a $g(b,c)=\frac b{c^2}+5\frac{b^2}{c^3}+\frac 1b-\frac{b^2}{(b^2+c^2)^{3/2}}+...$

Comment: So we expressed a function with two arguments as a sum of infinetely many functions with one argument? Where is the benefit in that? As a context: I have an unknown function that scales like $f$ in the question (and I can calculate it numerically) and I want to fit some (two or three) values at the end to get as close as possible to that unkown function with an analytical formula.